# Linux file manager (Nautilus, Dolphin. Thunar, etc...) SFTP through intermediate server

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I need to transfer files, as I would normally do, with my Linux file manager (Nautilus) via SFTP. However, in this specific case, I can't connect directly to the REMOTE server. I need to connect first to an INTERMEDIATE server, where I have copied my public key, so I can authenticate without a password. I am not allowed to do so on REMOTE (mandatory login with password.)

Is there some way I can get Nautilus (or any Linux file manager) to connect to the final REMOTE server through INTERMEDIATE?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the `ProxyJump` option in your SSH config:
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump

If the hostname of your intermediate server was `intermediate` and the hostname of your final server was `fileserver`, your config file would 
look something like this:

```
Host fileserver
Hostname my-fileserver


Host intermediate
Hostname intermediate-server
ProxyJump fileserver
```